# Function with return type typedef struct not working in VS2015

Tags: c, visual-studio

I defined a type using typedef of the type struct:

```
// Declate a new struct LVAL
typedef struct {
    int type;
    long num;
    int err;
} lval;
```

And then tried to declare a function using the return type lval(created above using typedef):

```
// Create a new number type lval
lval lval_num(long x)
{
    lval v;
    v.type = LVAL_NUM;
    v.num = x;
    return v;
}
```

But Visual Studio 2015, doesn't compile it, shows no errors, just these two:

```
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
Error   C2065   'x': undeclared identifier
```

Can anyone spot the bug/error? I tried Googling and other workarounds nothing worked.
Here's the full code snippet:

```
    // Create enumerations of possible lval struct types
enum { LVAL_NUM, LVAL_ERR };

// Create enumerations of possible lval error types.
enum { LERR_DIV_ZERO, LERR_BAD_OP, LERR_BAD_NUM };

// Declate a new struct LVAL
typedef struct {
    int type;
    long num;
    int err;
} lval;

// Create a new number type lval
lval lval_num(long x)
{
    lval v;
    v.type = LVAL_NUM;
    v.num = x;
    return v;
}
```

I tried declaring the function as this too but didn't work:

```
struct lval lval_num(long x)
{
    lval v;
    v.type = LVAL_NUM;
    v.num = x;
    return v;
}
```

EDIT: This is working on LINUX using gcc, but not on Windows(VS2015)
Here's a snap though.[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCxDA.jpg)

Comment: 1. You don't need `struct` once `typedef`ed. 2. Which line is line#160? 3. Does your error go away when you delete (comment) the function? 4. Does it work if you comment line `c.type = LVAL_NUM;`?

Comment: This is line# 160
`v.num = x;`

Comment: Is there something before enums? Are there some header files included? I mean no standard includes.

Comment: Does Visual Studio even support `//` comments? If not, that might be the reason.

Comment: @MohitJain Yes the errors do go away after commenting out the function.
Yes! I removed the `struct` in the declaration now. That was just for testing!

Comment: @SaifAli You may have introduced some strange unicode/multibyte characters in the function. Check which line causes issue. Delete that line and re-type the line. Or better rewrite the function. But no copy-paste.

Comment: @Lundin I'll appreciate your help, not feedback or criticism about VS,
It's the single best IDE I've ever used.
PS I love the amazing debugger and it does support `//` style commenting!

Comment: @SaifAli I don't doubt it is amazing, with the minor side-effect that it doesn't compile programs correctly. But who cares about that anyway.

Comment: @MohitJain I retyped it carefully again. and the same issue, though now you get a tidbit from VS, something like this:
[imgur](http://imgur.com/NK2uVND)

Comment: @SaifAli How did you declare the function `lval_num`?

Comment: `lval lval_num(long x)
 {
  lval v;
  v.type = LVAL_NUM;
  v.num = x;
  return v;
 }`

Like this..

Comment: @SaifAli This is definition. How did you declare?

Comment: @MohitJain I didn't declare it, though I did it like this 
`lval lval_num(long);`
and also like this
`lval lval_num(long x);`
And yes with typedef above it.
No good! But let me check that again!

Comment: @SaifAli You can also try by changing the name of the function to `lval_num_x`.

Comment: @MohitJain I just did that, and also declared the function before main() using a prototype. But no good same issue

Answer (score 1):

I see no error in your code, so the error must be *before* this code. Probably another unterminated `{` or a missing `;`.

Note: there is no "workaround" for a syntax error. You must fix the syntax error. Unfortunatly compilers can be very unclear about where the actual error was encountered and only tells you where it got confused.

Comment: No! That cannot be, because the line numbers these errors are popping up at, are with or after the declaration. Not before.

Comment: @SaifAli But a problem with unterminated `{` is triggered at the last part of code where last `{` is coded. Paul answer is plausible.

Comment: That doesn't matter. The compiler is in the process of parsing something and comes at a point where it is expecting something else than a `{`. It now tries to compile a codeblock but finds that `x` is undeclared because it hasn't completed parsing the function declaration. As I said "comilers are unclear about..."

Comment: @SaifAli The part of code you gave compiles perfectly on my computer, with gcc. And I see no error.

Comment: @Boiethios Yes! It compiles perfectly on gcc here too.
@PaulOgilvie `x` is the argument that gets passed into the function if you see the declaration, so `x` is declared I believe.

Comment: @SaifAli Perhaps your compiler does not "know" anonymous enum ? Try to give a name to the enum.

Comment: @Boiethios Thanks for heads up, but I tried giving it an identifier, no good.

Comment: @SaifAli, `x` is declared in the code but due to the syntax error the compiler hasn't seen it as an argument. So as far as the compiler is concerned, taking the syntax error into account, `x` hasn't been declared at the parse point.

Answer (score -1):

When I added header file stdio.h and main(). It got compiled